# Remove duplicates node tags on a XML document using Java

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, xml-parsing

I have the following xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<tag>text<b><b>bold</b> bold again</b><b><br/>the end </tag>
```

I need to remove the duplicate tags but keep it's content so the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <tag>text<b>bold bold again</b>the end </tag>
```

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;


public class TakeDuplicatesXml{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse("/Users/youruser/code/Exercises/file.xml");

            //get node list
            List<String> aux = new ArrayList<String>();
            removeDuplicate(doc.getDocumentElement(), aux);

            //print the new document out
            printXmlDocument(doc);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void printXmlDocument(Document doc){
        try{
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
            System.out.println("XML IN String format is: \n" + writer.toString());
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
  //with recursion
    public static void removeDuplicate(Node node, List<String>  aux){

        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        //check if that node exists already
        if(aux.contains(node.getNodeName())){
            node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
        }else{
            //add node name to aux list
            aux.add(node.getNodeName());
        }

        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                //calls this method for all the children which is Element
                removeDuplicate(currentNode, aux);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is not what I want because is taking the node with it's contents (the word bold is gone):

```
<tag>text<b> bold again</b><br/>the end </tag>
```

How can I fix it? And how can I make it more performant?

Comment: @GeroldBroser that makes sense but how do I now if the node was before or after the rest of the content inside the node?

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible with a DOM parser. With a SAX parser you receive events for document items in a sequence. See [SAX, Events vs. Trees](http://www.saxproject.org/event.html)

Comment: And there's also [StAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) with which you can read _and_ write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem is best tackled using a simple XSLT transformation. You need a stylesheet with two rules: an identity rule that copies everything unchanged

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and another (higher priority) rule that deletes nested b tags:

```
<xsl:template match="b/b">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Wrap these in the usual boilerplate:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http:www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

.. template rules go here ...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then invoke this from your Java program using:

public class TakeDuplicatesXml{

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Templates t = tFactory.newTemplates(new File(... stylesheet file ....));
        Source doc = new StreamSource(
          new File("/Users/youruser/code/Exercises/file.xml"));
        t.newTransformer().transform(doc, new StreamResult(System.out));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<b>bold</b>` is a child of `<b> bold again</b>.` If you perform `node.getParentNode().removeChild(node)` it is gone. Add the value of the child to the value of the parent before removing it.

Another possibility for querying XML is XPath. See [XPath Tutorial](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html):

- [Example 12](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example12.html): *"The descendant axis contains the descendants of the context node; a descendant is a child or a child of a child and so on".*
- [Example 8](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example8.html): *"Function name() returns name of the element".*

Can't tell if this is more performant. But I guess it is - in favour of a self-written recursion.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution. I am still not sure if it's the most optimal solution but works well and puts the contents in the right order:

```
//with recursion
    public static void removeDuplicate(Node node, List<String>  aux){


        //check if that node exists already
        if(aux.contains(node.getNodeName())){

            Node parentNode = node.getParentNode();
            String value = parentNode.getTextContent();

            parentNode.removeChild(node);
            parentNode.setTextContent(value);
        }else{
            //add node name to aux list
            aux.add(node.getNodeName());
        }

        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                //calls this method for all the children which is Element
                removeDuplicate(currentNode, aux);
            }
        }
```